# How to convert JSON (OData) time in something like gg-mm-aaaa in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, date, time, odata

I've a JSON like this ...

```
{
"d": {
    "__count": "5798",
    "results": [{
        "time": "\/Date(1467039720000+0120)\/",
        "internalId": "5771271b84aed43d477c901b",
        "datasetVersion": 3,
        "idDataset": "1214",
    }, {
        "time": "\/Date(1467036120000+0120)\/",
        "internalId": "577118c784aed43d477bdf90",
        "datasetVersion": 3,
        "idDataset": "1215",
 .....
```

and I'd like to extract and convert the time in a format like gg-mm-aaaa using javascript (or PHP if necessary ...).

Note that I know that "*+120*" are minutes ... so 2 hours.

Is there any javascript library or code sample to make this transformation?

Comment: moment.js does exactly what you need (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/) and all kinds of other tasks related to JS date processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
function FormatDate(value) {
    var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
    var results = pattern.exec(value);
    var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
    console.log(dt);
    console.log(dt.getMonth());
    console.log((dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear());
}
```

For example

```
FormatDate("/Date(1467039720000+0120)/");
```

Output:

```
Mon Jun 27 2016 11:02:00 GMT-0400 (US Eastern Daylight Time)
VM64:50 5
VM64:51 6/27/2016
```

Here is the fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/jkqm4ej3/

Answer (score 2):

Moment JS is a very good library for dealing with time / dates.  You'll probably need to parse out the string value in your JSON to send it to moment though.
http://momentjs.com/